# Are questions about English learning on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've seen the following question:
[Are questions about individual languages on-topic?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-individual-languages-on-topic/30#30)
And the most up-voted answer suggests that questions about a specific language are on-topic as long as they involve with learning that specific language. So this can be applied to questions about English-learning.
But as you know we already have a graduated site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Then what will be the difference between English learning questions that should be asked here and the ones that should be asked on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'd personally say that you *can* ask questions about learning English here, but it might be *better* to ask them on ELL.

Answer (score 10):

Questions about the **techniques and methods** used to learn English (or any other language) are on-topic here. Anything about the actual English language should be asked on ELL or EL&U.

To clarify, LL is for questions about language learning techniques.
ELL is for really basic questions about English like, "Is XYZ an adjective?"
ELU is for fluent English speakers asking about vocabulary, phrases, grammar, or syntax of English.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about how to learn English are on topic here. Questions about the English language itself should be asked on ELL or EL&U.

Comment: Well then what will be the difference between ELL and EL&U?

Comment: That should be well covered on those respective sites' FAQs and metas, and is mostly off-topic here.

Comment: Note that questions about how to learn English are also on-topic on ELL, and that sites can have overlap, so something being on-topic on one doesn't change what's on-topic on the other.

Answer (score 1):

English Language Learners is for people that are studying English as a "second" language but are advanced enough to learn English *in English.*

This site is for people who are still struggling with English, and are asking, "How can I learn English using my native tongue as a "base?"

Comment: I don't understand; [this site is to be in English](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/13/19), right? If one doesn't know enough English to learn about it in English, how will they interact on this site?